# Question about google login on react native expo mobile application

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth

Hi guys i have a question about google login on react native using expo. I'm currently using a login that is like the google login but this login didn't show me the accounts already in use on the phone. I sow a lot of application that when you click on google login it displays all google accounts that you have on your phone. Doese any one knows how to do that? Please ask if you need some code i will update my question